# How to stop HP keyboard redirect

Tags: keyboard

Hi I have a windows machine from HP.

I think they have some kind of keyboard redirect that takes me to a HP website on certain (seemingly random) key presses.

It is very annoying - how can I disable it please?

```
EDIT 1
```

I believe it is NOT a keyboard hardware issue, but rather some software redirection that HP has applied to the keyboard mapping.

Comment: I don't think this is a question related to programming... Maybe you're on the wrong website.

Comment: buy another keyboard? (they're not exactly expensive)

Comment: Play around a bit so you can be more specific than "seemingly random". And the right site is probably [su].

Comment: @fero - can you suggest a suitable forum please?

Comment: @Spudley I don't think it's a keyboard issue...

Comment: @ManInMoon [su] is a more suitable forum, though I'm not sure whether this question is currently answerable (because (1) Your steps to reproduce are near non-existent and (2) I strongly doubt HP (or anyone) would release PCs that goes to its (or any) website from random key presses), but, who knows, maybe I'm wrong and this is a common issue, or it isn't, but someone has come across it before.

Comment: @Dukeling It is a very common issue - when I google it. Problem is everyone thinks it's a browser virus. But I don not. And as for HP - they definitely do it - I guess they did not think it would be an issue. Just a nice way to get you to look at their website... Are you able to tell me how to migrate this to SuperUser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google "HP keyboard redirect" found this:

[HP Communities - XP Keyboard Drivers: HP redirect. - Enterprise Business Community](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Home-PCs-Pavilion-Presario/XP-Keyboard-Drivers-HP-redirect/td-p/54940)

Excerpt with the instructions:

> 1. Go to Control Panel.
> 2. Go into Keyboard, and click on "Buttons" tab (on top).
> 3. Then double-click on any one of the internet link entries ("globe within an open door" icons), in the "Configure a keyboard button" box.
> 4. Now click on the drop down menu arrow, to the right of the "Choose a button capability" and,,
> 5. Select "Complex remote page with label" and make sure to type the website address (url) of you choice, down below. I assume you know you
>      can type in whatever label you want for each, also.
>
> Do this for each of the 7 or so internet link entries. (the first 4
>   "computer icon" links don't apply, as they link to local files on your
>   system).

Comment: Thanks - oddly, I searched for ages and never came across this. But that appears to have done the trick.